# Parsing a log file containing possible line changes with SED

Tags: parsing, logging, sed

I am printing a log file with PHP which unfortunately, contains

```
0000000001 foo.php:123 This is a message\n
0000000002 foo.php:124 This is a message, line 1\n
line 2\n
line 3\n
```

Using sed,

```
s/^\([0-9]{10}\) \(^[\s]*\) \(.*\)$/
```

I can get line 1 and 2 above, but not 3 and 4 because they do not match the pattern; I would like to conditionally remove line breaks, for example in the above log, merge lines 2..4.

Can I have the last (.*) to match "until I hit a new line with the beginning   ^[0-9]{10}   ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using awk, you can format your file like this where all lines not beginning with a number are merged. You can apply your sed to this:

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]/{if (x)print x;x="";}{x=x $0;}END{print x}' file
0000000001 foo.php:123 This is a message\n
0000000002 foo.php:124 This is a message, line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;/\n[0-9]\{10\}/!s/\n//;ta;P;D' file
```